# problema com galeria para abrir e fechar elementos

Tags: javascript, html5, galeria

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma galeria de fotos em meu site, quando você clica na foto aparece um box com um texto e uma imagem lateral, explicando sobre a imagem segue um `print` 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Clicando no x fecha normal porem se eu clicar em outra imagem abre a box referente a imagem que eu cliquei, porem a primeira não fecha ai fica uma em cima da outra e na hora de fechar fica tendo que fechar uma por uma, ou seja se o cara clicou em 8 imagens antes de fechar no x ele vai ter que ir fechando manualmente depois. Queria saber se tem alguma forma de consertar isso para para que quando a pessoa já tiver abrido uma box ao clicar em outra imagem a box que estava aberta feche segue meu código:

HTML:

```
<div class="wmg-item work-screenshots">
                                    <div class="wmg-thumbnail">
                                        <div class="wmg-thumbnail-content">
                                            <!-- exemplo de conteudo para thumbnail -->
                                            <img src="http://www.missnikkey.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/350x350.gif" alt="image">
                                            <!-- fim do exemplo -->
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="wmg-arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wmg-details">
                                    <!-- <span class="wmg-close"></span> -->
                                    <i class="fa fa-times wmg-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <div class="wmg-details-content">
                                        <!-- exemplo de coteúdo para detail -->
                                        <div class="container description-work">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <img src="http://www.htreafarms.com/images/new-family-photos/blank.jpg" alt="image">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                                                    <h2 class="title-work">Decathlon</h2>
                                                    <hr class="bar">
                                                    <h4>Cliente desde - <span>2006</span></h4>
                                                    <p class="text-work">
                                                        Fundada em 1976 é hoje um dos maiores varejistas do mundo no segmento esportivo, a rede francesa Decathlon está presente no Brasil desde 2001, quando abriu sua primeira loja em Campinas, no interior paulista. Hoje conta com 11 lojas no Brasil e 535 no Mundo.
                                                    </p>
                                                    <a href="#" target="_BLANK" class="prt_btn">Visite o site</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- fim do exemplo -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div><!-- .wmg-item -->
```

JS

```
$(".work-screenshots").slice(0, 6).show();
    $("#loadMore-works").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".work-screenshots:hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown();
        if ($(".work-screenshots:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Com os códigos postados não se consegue reproduzir o problema

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo vou atualizar os códigos